# What subscript $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ means?

Tags: notation, integers

I knew $\mathbb{Z}$ symbol means integer numbers set.

[image: img1]

But what is the meaning of subscript "$p$" in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

[image: img2]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_p=\{[0],\dots,[p-1]\}$, where $[k]$ is a congruence class, and is called the **ring of integers modulo p**. $p$ is usually assumed to be a prime.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n) recommends you use $\mathbb{Z}/ p\mathbb{Z}$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

It means set of equivalence classes of integers modulo $p$.

Answer (score 1):

It represents the integers module p where p is usually prime :) I assume you've dealt with the modular arithmetic?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is the integers modulo $p$, but sometimes it is the $p$-adic integers.